# How to highlight the searched item in Far manager?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlighting, far-manager

Whenever I search an item(F7; Shift+F7) in a file via far manager editor(F4), I have trouble finding my cursor under the found item. It takes time to find it in the lines of code.
How can I highlight the found item or the whole line in far editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search with f7 you can check the box "mark result".

Comment: thanks, very straightforward, how could I have not noticed that)